# process([command]) { read } のような文法の名前を知りたい

Tags: ruby, redis

RubyのRedisクライアントのソースコード(redis4.0.1)を読んでいると、
`lib/redis/client.rb`
というファイルに

```
def call(command)
      reply = process([command]) { read }
      raise reply if reply.is_a?(CommandError)
......
```

という記述がありました。

```
process([command]) { read }
```

この`[]`閉じと、`{ }` の文法の名前をググりたいのですがどういうワードでググればいいのか見当がつかないので、知っている方がいれば教えていただきたいです

追記 2020/6/27
こちらが参考になりました。
http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_blocks.html

Comment: スタック・オーバーフローでは[自己回答](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)ができ、また推奨されています。ご自身なりの回答もぜひ（質問への追記ではなく）回答として投稿してみてください :)　URL だけだとリンク切れしたときに回答の意味が薄れてしまうので、ご自身なりの解釈も書かれていると寿命の長い回答になります。こちらも是非お試しください。

Answer (score 3):

記号をググるのは難しいので、Rubyの場合はリファレンスマニュアルの「Rubyで使われる記号の意味」のページを参照すると意味がつかめると思います。
https://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/latest/doc/symref.html

英単語としてググるなら、brackets, braces, curly braces, parenthesesなどの単語が適切でしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます！
Rubyのyieldとブロックに対する理解が浅かったようです。調べ方参考になります